# Isolate TLD from FQDN using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to isolate TLDs utilizing regex from giant lists of FQDNs without importing 3rd party modules and am attempting to determine if there is a more eloquent way of doing this. My way works but is a bit cumbersome for my liking.

Sample code:

```
domains = ['x.sample1.com', 'y.sample2.org', 'z.sample3.biz']
temp = []
for domain in domains:
    temp.append(re.findall('\.[a-z0-9]+', domain, re.I)
tlds = []
for item in temp:
    for tld in item:
        tlds.append(tld)
```

It is inconvenient how the return of the re.findall is a list object as it makes the iterating process an entire level deeper than desired but am unsure of how to get around this.

Comment: It's impossible. You need a list of TLDs.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Not quite sure if you read my entire question, but I just said my way works. It's just cumbersome.

Comment: While are you doing this without importing a third-party module? How do you want to handle `example.co.uk`? What do you expect to get for the samples you provide? Currently, `len(tlds) == 6`.

Comment: If you only want the last part after the last dot, split by dot and take the last item, like this: `domain.split('.')[-1]`

Comment: @phihag This is a script that may be executed by individuals that don't have access to third party modules so I'm trying to keep it to the standard library.

Comment: @JackBurton Why not save the third party library in a `vendor` folder, and include it with your script?

Answer (score 1):

The "quick fix" is either to take the last item in each array:

```
split('.', domain)[-1]
```

Or, if you really don't care about the first matches, then don't capture them at all:

```
re.find('\.[a-z0-9]+$', domain, re.I)
```

(Note the use of `$` to match the end of string.)

HOWEVER, note that it's impossible to solve this problem properly with regex. For example, how can you know that the TLD for `google.co.uk` is `co.uk`, and not just `uk`?

The only full solution to this problem, unfortunately, is by using a library that implements the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/) - which is basically just a very long (manually updated) list of all TLDs. For example, in python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix/

Comment: In your example: `google.co.uk` the TLD is `.uk` not `co.uk` 

The final text string after the final dot is the TLD country code. Whatever precedes it is not the TLD. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk